# Slicing with Multindexing with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, slice, multi-index

I am trying to slice using Multindexing in both axes simultaneously but I get an exception:

```
multi_index_0 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A', 'B', 'C'], ['a' , 'b']], names=['first', 'second'])
multi_index_1 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['D', 'E'], ['c' , 'd']], names=['first', 'second'])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6, 4), multi_index_0, multi_index_1)
```

Now, I want to slice rows ['A', 'b] and ['B', 'a'], and columns ['D', 'c'] and ['E', 'd'].

I have tried unsuccessfully the following:

```
df.loc[['A', 'b'], ['B', 'a']], [['D', 'c'], ['E', 'd']]
```

rerurns empty dataframe

```
df.loc[['A', 'B'], ['b', 'a']], [['D', 'E'], ['c', 'd']]
```

returns empty dataframe

```
df.loc[([['A', 'B'], ['b', 'a']]), ([['D', 'E'], ['c', 'd']])]

TypeError: '['A', 'B']' is an invalid key

df.loc[([['A', 'b'], ['B', 'a']]), ([['D', 'c'], ['E', 'd']])]

TypeError: '['A', 'b']' is an invalid key
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly as it is, multi-indexing works with tuples but not with lists... (probably for good reasons, to avoid ambiguity in edge cases I can't thing of on the spot). So you can just do:

```
df.loc[[('A','b'),('B','a')], [('D', 'c'), ('E', 'd')]]
```

Of course jezrael's solution works, too, I just find this to be a bit more elegant (and possibly faster.)

[EDIT]: Your first command `df.loc[['A', 'b'], ['B', 'a']], [['D', 'c'], ['E', 'd']]` returns an empty DataFrame because you missed brackets, so actually you're effectively doing `df.loc[['A', 'b'], ['B', 'a']]` (plus a list on the side, so the answer will be a tuple of empty df + list). This to Pandas means: please give me all the elements such that, at the same time:

- Have index that starts with A *or* with b
- Have column that starts with B *or* with a.

Since there is no such column, you get an empty frame.

You probably meant: `df.loc[[['A', 'b'], ['B', 'a']], [['D', 'c'], ['E', 'd']]]`, that, however, gives an exception because, again, you're using lists instead of tuples.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.isin.html) for boolean mask and then select by `loc`:

```
m1 = df.index.isin((['A', 'b'], ['B', 'a']))
m2 = df.columns.isin((['D', 'c'], ['E', 'd']))

df = df.loc[m1, m2]
print (df)
first                D         E
second               c         d
first second                    
A     b      -0.915119 -0.038221
B     a      -1.224615 -0.873551
```